# Convergence of improper integral of c.d.f.

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals, uniform-convergence, cumulative-distribution-functions

Let $F(x),G(x)$ be two cumulative distribution functions. And
$$
\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty}|x|dF(x)<\infty,\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty}|x|dG(x)<\infty
$$
show that:
$$
\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty}|F(x)-G(x)|dx<\infty
$$
I try to do this by
\begin{aligned}
\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty}xdF(x)-\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty}xdG(x) = \int^{+\infty}_{-\infty}G(x)-F(x)dx<\infty 
\end{aligned}
Then I don't know how to continue, since convergence doesn't imply absolute convergence. Maybe this is the wrong direction.

Answer (score 1):

By triangle inequality and linearity of expectation,
$$
\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty}|F(x)-G(x)|dx \leq \int^{+\infty}_{-\infty} F(x) + G(x)dx \leq \mathbb{E}_G [|X|] +  \mathbb{E}_F [|X|]  <\infty,
$$
since
$$
\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty}|x|dF(x) = \mathbb{E}_F [|X|] <\infty,
$$
where $\mathbb{E}_F$ denotes expectation w.r.t. the CDF $F$.